# Anaconda show env base

Tags: conda

That's my problem
How can I remove (base) after I deactivate another env

First time I open terminal, it won't show (base)
but after I deactivate , it will show
like picture
How should I set?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get in or out of your base environment? `conda activate base` or `conda deactivate` will do either, no matter which environment you're in.

```
(base) [~] conda activate py36
(py36) [~] which python
/Users/mwt/miniconda3/envs/py36/bin/python
(py36) [~] conda deactivate
(base) [~] which python
/Users/mwt/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) [~] conda deactivate
[~] which python
/usr/bin/python
[~] conda activate base
(base) [~] which python
/Users/mwt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

The **base** environment can be activated with either `conda activate base` or just `conda activate`. There is also a setting to auto-activate **base** when shell opens, that can be enabled with

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base true
```

Comment: it's not working for me .
It won't show (base) first time
but will show after 「conda deactivate some-env」